# Creating multidimensional array on the heap

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, c++14, language-lawyer, heap-memory

After some experiments I've come up with these four ways of creating multidimensional array on the heap (1 and 2 is kinda the same except that the result for 1 I wanted reference):

```
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
void printArr(T const &arr)
{
    std::cout << typeid(T).name() << "\t";
    for (int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
        for (int y = 0; y < 2; ++y)
            for (int z = 0; z < 2; ++z)
                std::cout << arr[x][y][z] << " ";
    std::cout << std::endl;
}


int main()
{
    int(&arr)[2][2][2] = reinterpret_cast<int(&)[2][2][2]>(*new int[2][2][2]{ { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } }, { { 5,6 },{ 7,8 } } });
    printArr(arr);
    delete[] &arr;

    int(*arr2)[2][2] = new int[2][2][2]{ { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } },{ { 5,6 },{ 7,8 } } };
    printArr(arr2);
    delete[] arr2;

    std::unique_ptr<int[][2][2]> arr3(new int[2][2][2]{ { { 1,2 },{ 3,4 } },{ { 5,6 },{ 7,8 } } });
    printArr(arr3);

    std::unique_ptr<int[][2][2]> arr4 = std::make_unique<int[][2][2]>(2);
    printArr(arr4);

    return 0;
}
```

Tested this on various online compilers without problems, so what I would like to know if they are valid ways as well?

Here is the demo https://ideone.com/UWXOoW and output:

```
int [2][2][2]   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
int (*)[2][2]   1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
class std::unique_ptr<int [0][2][2],struct std::default_delete<int [0][2][2]> > 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
class std::unique_ptr<int [0][2][2],struct std::default_delete<int [0][2][2]> > 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: I think the first is UB, the other three are OK.

Comment: @geza Hmm, what makes you think it is UB?

Comment: Ehh. Why not just use a `std::vector`?

Comment: @JesperJuhl Too easy ))) Well something made me curious plus it was a good exercise

Comment: You should, in general, not use a reference as an *owning* copy of anything. Other programmers expect that a reference refers to something which exists somewhere else, and the reference can go out of scope without issue. If you need to delete something at the end, you should use something like `unique_ptr`, or at least an owning pointer instead of reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your first example is undefined behavior or at least would lead to undefined behavior as soon as you'd try to actually access the array through the reference `arr`.

`new int[2][2][2]` creates an array of two `int[2][2]`. It returns you a pointer to the first element of this array ([[expr.new] §1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.new#1)). However, a pointer to the first element of an array and a pointer to the array itself are not [*pointer interconvertible*](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-4). I'm not sure if there is a definitive answer yet to the philosophical question "does the act of dereferencing an invalid pointer itself already constitute undefined behavior?". But at least accessing the reference obtained from your reinterpret_cast should definitely violate the [strict aliasing rule](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#11). The other three should be fine.

#### Edit:

As there still seems to be some confusion, here a more detailed explanation of my argument:

```
new int[2][2][2]
```

creates an array of two `int[2][2]` and returns a pointer to the first element of this array, i.e., a pointer to the first `int[2][2]` subobject *within* this array and *not the complete array object itself*.

If you want to get an `int(*)[2][2][2]` from `new`, you could, e.g., do

```
new int[1][2][2][2]
```

Comment: I don't think pointer interconvertibility is applicable in here, as I am reinterpreting lvalue via a reference `An lvalue expression of type T1 can be converted to reference to another type T2. The result is an lvalue or xvalue referring to the same object as the original lvalue, but with a different type. No temporary is created, no copy is made, no constructors or conversion functions are called. The resulting reference can only be accessed safely if allowed by the type aliasing rules`. Type aliasing rules could be the problem though.

Comment: I believe this is the wording from the old C++03 standard!? At least to my understanding, the current wording regarding this would be [\[expr.reinterpret.cast\] §11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.reinterpret.cast#11) which defines `reinterpret_cast` of references via casting of pointers. Aliasing rules should definitely be a problem either way I think.

Comment: I posted an alternative answer, thanks to your link, where it shows that it is not UB, please check

Comment: Would [`std::launder`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder) be valid? There is an object of type `int[2][2][2]` there; it's just that you didn't convert the pointer in a valid way.

Comment: I was also thinking about that, as the standard [explicitly mentions in a note](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.types#basic.compound-4) that an array and the first element have the same address. I would be inclined to say yes, but I'm not 100% sure…

Comment: `If you want to dynamically create an int[2][2][2], you can use

new (int[2][2][2])` This is what I did, I created `int[2][2][2]` in the first place with new, this is why it is hard to understand why making the reference `int(&)[2][2][2]` to it is UB?

Comment: Actually, scratch that. I was mistaken to believe that the parentheses would change anything. But it actually doesn't matter whether you do `new int[2][2][2]` or `new (int[2][2][2])`, you will get an `int(*)[2][2]` either way. I removed that part from my answer above.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Excuse my nitpicking, but the actual array bounds are in the leftmost `[]`, not the rightmost.

Comment: `you will get an int(*)[2][2] either way` this doesn't change the fact that the memory is allocated and initialised for `int[2][2][2]`,Unfortunately I cannot just reference it directly because new  returns a pointer

Comment: @HolyBlackCat you're correct, Sir. Nitpicking is always welcome, just made me realize that my mental model of the new expression grammar was not entirely right. Always glad to learn something…corrected my answer yet again… =)

Comment: `do new int[1][2][2][2]` That is an interesting suggestion, which probably deserves a separate question.

Comment: I've added quote from the standard why the reinterpret_cast I marked ok is ok

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Not only will parentheses not help, `using my_3d_arr = int[2][2][2]; my_3d_arr* arr = new my_3d_arr;` doesn't even do the trick. The `new` expression actually cares about the type, not whether you use square brackets.

Comment: @DanielH yes, I somehow thought that `new` only cared about "top-level" `[]` that actually appear in the new expression because it needs special handling of those to allow for dynamic array bounds (since dynamic array bounds could not be expressed as part of the type system). I was wrong, though. It does have such special handling as part of the grammar. However, the standard also defines `new` to behave in the same way for of both, static and dynamic "top-level" array bounds, which is a detail I seem to not have been aware of until now…

Comment: @KillzoneKid The `reinterpret_cast` itself is ok indeed. It's also ok to just `reinterpret_cast` a random integer into a pointer. That doesn't change anything about the fact that it's not necessarily ok to then dereference the pointer obtained from this cast…

Comment: @MichaelKenzel what if I cast to `void*` first, then from `void*` to another type. It is guaranteed that the size of the resulting object will fit because it will be the same memory remapped. As I understood the problem could arise from optimisation, but casting to `void*` should give compiler clue not to do something unwanted.

Comment: Casting to `void*` will not change anything, that's what `reinterpret_cast` does in the end anyways. You either have undefined behavior or you don't. I think that, in this case, you have undefined behavior. I believe what you're trying to do is ultimately bound to violate the strict aliasing rule no matter how you're going to do it exactly. I don't think there currently is a well-defined way to get to a complete array object given a pointer to its first element. I was not able to find an example where a compiler will actually break such code. But that doesn't mean it's correct code to write…

Comment: There is no such thing as a "clue not to do something unwanted". You either have well-defined behavior, in which case you know what your program is going to do, or you don't. A particular compiler may give additional guarantees for certain language constructs beyond what the standard offers. Code that relies on such guarantees may then be guaranteed to work when compiled with that particular version of that particular compiler. But it is not portable standard C++ anymore. You will find information about such guarantees in the documentation of your compiler. If not, then no guarantees exists…

Comment: I should note that, as @DanielH pointed out, `std::launder()` *may* be a way to actually do what you want to do in a well-defined manner. But I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @MichaelKenzel Then I’ll ask it as another question and link here when I get a chance, probably tonight. Also, note that Clang does give some guarantees beyond the standard but does not document them; the guarantees still exist within a particular compiler version and are still mostly stable between versions. People don’t always document everything they should.

Comment: _does the act of dereferencing an invalid pointer_ Where do you see an invalid pointer? _But at least accessing the reference obtained from your reinterpret_cast should definitely violate the strict aliasing rule_ There is no such thing as «accessing a reference».